# Can I display Yes or No instead of 0 or 1 in Wordpress admin table view (WP_List_Table) using add_action or add_filter?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress plugin that uses its own database table.

When I display the table on my plugins page all the database table data is returned correctly, but what I would like to do is to show the 0 or 1 boolean values as No or Yes.

So I want to Change this
[image]
Into this
[image]

I've searched https://codex.wordpress.org (which is poorly documented) but I could not find any Wordpress functions I can call to manipulate outputted values from a database table. At the moment I'm using jQuery to fix this but it just seems a bit hacky to me.

```
// Change the testimonials boolean values from 0 or 1 to Yes or No and M or F to Male or Female
function parseTestimonials() {
    echo '<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("td:contains(\'1\').show_testimonial").each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).text("No");
                });

                jQuery("td:contains(\'0\').show_testimonial").each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).text("Yes");
                });

                jQuery("td:contains(\'M\').gender").each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).text("Male");
                });

                jQuery("td:contains(\'F\').gender").each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).text("Female");
                });
            });
        </script>';
}

add_action('in_admin_footer', 'parseTestimonials');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the class you use to extend the list table you should be able to do something like the code below where mycolumnname is the name you gave to the column.

You can create custom functions for any column in a list table by preceding it with function column_

$item will be the database result row and $column_name will be the database result field (assuming you named your columns the same as your database fields).  If not, you can:

```
$switch ($item['myfieldname']) {
```

otherwise

```
function column_mycolumnname($item, $column_name)
        {
          switch ($item[$column_name]) {
             case '0':
                return 'Yes';
             case '1':
                return 'No';
             case 'M':
                return 'Male';
             case 'F':
                return 'Female';
             default: 
                //doesn't match the above so return the database field contents
                return $item[$column_name];
            }
    }
```

In another example, here's how to add a checkbox to a database 'ID' field where the name of the listtable column is 'cb':

```
function column_cb($item)
        {
        return sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="%s" />', $item['ID']);
        }
```

With that, you can $_GET the database ID of any row that the user has put a checkbox in without actually showing the ID number.

edit - oops, looks like you already figured out checkbox fields. Same principle.